# Capistrano 2, SSH, Mac, EC2 - Permission Denied on Write

Tags: macos, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, capistrano

So I'm using WP-Stack and trying to deploy from my local machine to an EC2 instance.

Ive follow capistrano's SSH literature and I can for instance get the server info by just running SSH and the user/IP

I have created the user 'deploy' on my EC2 server, I have ensured it has permissions to write the folders I want (infact I can go in and manually from CL do "mkdir /production/" without problems to create the directory Capistrano is trying to make. Ive searched and searched online and I can't find anything specific to my issue. Most seem to be folder's having the wrong errors.

So I have this in by deploy.rb

```
#
set :user, "deploy"
set :use_sudo, false
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :copy_exclude, [".git", ".gitmodules", ".DS_Store", ".gitignore"]
set :keep_releases, 5

after "deploy:update", "deploy:cleanup"
after "deploy:update_code", "shared:make_shared_dir"
after "deploy:update_code", "shared:make_symlinks"
after "deploy:update_code", "db:make_config"
after "deploy", "memcached:update"

# Pull in the config file
loadFile 'config/config.rb'
```

and in config

```
# Customize this file, and then rename it to config.rb

set :application, "myapp"
set :repository,  "git@bitbucket.org:user/mygit.git"
set :scm, :git
# Or: `accurev`, `bzr`, `cvs`, `darcs`, `git`, `mercurial`, `perforce`, `subversion` or `none`

# Using Git Submodules?
set :git_enable_submodules, 1

# This should be the same as :deploy_to in production.rb
set :production_deploy_to, '/var/www/vhost/i-16852366/production/'

# The domain name used for your staging environment
set :staging_domain, 'stage.domain.com'

# Database
# Set the values for host, user, pass, and name for both production and staging.
set :wpdb do
{
    :production => {
        :host     => 'user.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com',
        :user     => 'user',
        :password => 'pass',
        :name     => 'name',
    },
    :staging => {
        :host     => 'user.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com',
        :user     => 'user',
        :password => 'pass',
        :name     => 'name2',
    }
}
end

 # You're not done! You must also configure production.rb and staging.rb
```

and finally for production

```
# This file is only loaded for the production environment
# Customize it and rename it as production.rb

# Where should the site deploy to?
set :deploy_to, '/var/www/vhost/i-16852366/production/'

 # Now configure the servers for this environment

 # OPTION 1

 # role :web, "your web server IP address or hostname here"
 # role :web, "second web server here"
 # role :web, "third web server here, etc"

 # OPTION 2

 # If your web servers are the same as your memcached servers,
 # comment out all the "role" lines and use "server" lines:

server "54.242.153.162", :web, :memcached
```

But when I try 'cap deploy:setup' or 'cap deploy:check' it can't write to folders I can create from command prompt with the deploy user

```
servers: ["54.242.153.162"]
[54.242.153.162] executing command
** [out :: 54.242.153.162] mkdir: cannot create directory `/var/www/vhost': Permission denied
** [out :: 54.242.153.162] mkdir: cannot create directory `/var/www/vhost': Permission denied
** [out :: 54.242.153.162] mkdir: cannot create directory `/var/www/vhost': Permission denied
command finished in 600ms
failed: "sh -c 'mkdir -p /var/www/vhost/i-16852366/production/ /var/www/vhost/i-    16852366/production/releases /var/www/vhost/i-16852366/production/shared &&  chmod g+w     /var/www/vhost/i-16852366/production/ /var/www/vhost/i-16852366/production/releases    /var/www/vhost/i-16852366/production/shared'" on 54.242.153.162
```

Any ideas? Is it due to the .tem file not being used? I can't find a tutorial that shows how to use it if so.

Answer (score 0):

Access via SSH to an EC2 instance uses a regular user - for the Amazon AMI, for example, you will log in as ec2-user.

/var/www is owned by root, so the ec2-user will not be able to create a subdirectory.

I'd start by changing this line to true:

```
set :use_sudo, false
```

Comment: My image uses root as the main users. I'm not using the Amazon AMI's, I'm using the animo to wordpress Nginx one, http://megumi-cloud.com/category/blog/

Ive created a deploy user and as stated it can ssh in just fine and create directories which it owns in the web root, there is nothing wrong with my user setup. Oh and i tried the sudo false to true just to try, but still doesn't work.

Comment: What are the permissions on /var/www?